# What happens to the shared folder of a oracle virtual box when exporting it?

Tags: virtualbox

I have an oracle virtual box with Ubuntu as guest on a windows host, with a shared folder between the two. I want to transfer it to a different computer. Therefore, I export the virtual box. But I am unsure if I need to copy the shared folder separately.

**What** happens to the data in the shared folder when I export the virtual box using the VirtualBox Manager (file > export) to a .ova-file? Is it included in this file or does it belong to the host and I have to transfer it additionally?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser! The fact that the folders can be _transient_ or _permanent_ and that the _Shared folders physically reside on the host and are then shared with the guest, which uses a special file system driver in the Guest Additions to talk to the host_, leads me to believe that you need to make a separate backup. They are usually exchange areas between VMs or with the HOST. You can however verify this with a shared folder with a file by exporting the machine, and importing the VM after changing the path on the HOST. If you see it and see the file, you don't need to make other backups.

Comment: Give it a look [sharedfolders](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/sharedfolders.html) page of virtualbox for more info.

Comment: Testing this would probably take less time than typing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shared folder is a folder of the host, that Virtualbox makes visible
to the guest VM.

So if you export the VM, the host folder is not physically part of
the export.

The documentation doesn't say what happens to the *definition* of the
shared folder, but probably you will need to re-create it on the new host.